# Как запустить php-скрипт по добавлению данных в БД на хостинге?

Tags: php, mysql

Товарищи, задача заполнить таблицу БД строками в количестве 5000шт данными с помощью чистого php.

id - INT,
name - TEXT,
surname - TEXT,
phone - INT

В корень сайта public_html положил скрипт с таким содержанием:

```
    <?php 

$server = "localhost";
$login = "dchetbkru";
$pass = "Dchetbkru4";
$name_db = "dchetbkru";

$link = mysqli_connect($server, $login, $pass, $name_db);

if($link == false)
{
    echo "Connection error";
}

$rowsToCreate = 3000;
$names = array("name1", "name2", "name3");
$surnames = array("text1", "text2", "text3");
$phones = array(1, 2, 3);
do {
    $sqlStr = "INSERT INTO `user_list` (name, surname, phone) VALUES ('" . array_fill($names[rand(0,3)]) . "', '" . array_fill($surnames[rand(0,3)]) . "', '" . array_fill($phones[rand(0,3)]) . "')";
         $result = mysqli_query($link, $sqlStr);

    $rowsToCreate--;

} while ($rowsToCreate>=0);

 $link->close();

if($result == false) {
    print('Произошла ошибка');
}

printf("Сообщение ошибки: %s\n", mysqli_error($link));

?>
```

Далее перехожу по ссылке: домен/sql.php, ошибки никакой не выдает, но БД не заполняется.

Что делаю не так? PHP и БД только второй день пробую, прошу помочь. Таблица, которую надо заполнить имеет название `Список людей`.

Comment: https://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.array-rand.php#refsect1-function.array-rand-examples

Comment: Да скобка у тебя незакрытая в запросе...

Comment: @Akina еще б запрос и выполнить не мешало)

Comment: В чём собственно проблема?

Comment: Скобку закрыл, запрос выполнил, но БД так и не заполняется нужной информацией. Что не так?

Comment: А какая информация - нужная?

Comment: Хотя выдает ошибку все таки. Нужная информация находится в  массивах names, surnames, phones. По задумке эти данные должны попасть в таблицу и заполнить строки соответствующими значениями, количество строк 5000.

Comment: https://www.php.net/manual/ru/mysqli.error.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. array_rand выбирает КЛЮЧ, а не значение из массива.
2. `Список людей` так таблица называется? кириллицей, это очень интересно
3. `$result = mysqli_query($link, $sqlStr);` надо все-таки поместить в цикл, иначе будет только одна запись добавлена

Comment: Большое спасибо, лед тронулся. Удалось создать массив нужной длины, но заполнить значениями из массивов не выходит. Пробовал функцию array_values, array_fill не помогает. Какую функцию посоветуете использовать?

Comment: добавьте строчку после mysqli_connect:

Comment: 1. добавьте строчку после mysqli_connect: /* Проверить соединение */
if ($link->connect_errno) {
    printf("Соединение не удалось: %s\n", $link->connect_error);
    exit();
} 2. после цикла закрывайте соединение:
$link->close();   3. добавьте в цикл, после получения result if (!$result) {
    printf("Сообщение ошибки: %s\n", $link->error);
}  4. исходя из вашего тз, что-то такое:   $names[rand(0,4)]